# Proof - Limits of CDF

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

For a cdf, defined as $F(x)=P(X\le x)$, in order to prove $\lim\limits_{x\,\uparrow\,\infty}F(x)=1$, I've two concerns: (1) Some concern about a proof from a book, and (2)Validity of a proof that I've chalked out. Would really appreciate your help on this.
**(1) Concern for a proof from a book**

> The proof goes like this
>   $\Omega=\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(-\infty,n]$
>   $P(\Omega)=1$, and
>   $P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-\infty, n]\right) = \lim_{_m\to\infty} P((-\infty, m])$  $\qquad$_...by ref (A). see below_
>   $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=\lim_{_m\to\infty} P(X\le m) = \lim_{_m\to\infty} F(m)$
>   Equating left and right side, we get $\lim_{_m\to\infty} F(m) = 1$

My concern here is that both $n$ and $m$ $\in\mathbb{N^+}$ where as the domain of a cdf must be real number i.e.  $x \in\mathbb{R}$ by definition. Thus above proof is valid for
$x$ $\in\mathbb{N^+}$  but not for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Am I missing something!!

**(2) Validity of my proof**
If we define intervals $(-\infty,x_1]$, $(-\infty,x_2]$.. such that $x_1, x_2,..\in\mathbb{R}$, and $x_1\lt x_2\lt ..\lt x_n..\lt x$ and then we've non-decreasing events (intervals) where $x_n\uparrow x$. Further, if  we make $x\to\infty$, then by the above setting we see that as $n\to\infty$ we've $x\to\infty$.

> Now we can proceed as,
>   $\Omega=\mathbb{R}=(-\infty,\infty)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(-\infty,x_n]$
>   $P(\Omega)=1$, and
>   $P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-\infty, x_n]\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} P((-\infty, x_n])$  $\qquad\qquad\qquad$_...step (I)_
>   $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=\lim_{x_n\uparrow x,\; x\to\infty} P((-\infty, x])$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$_...step (II)_
>   $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad= \lim_{x\uparrow\infty} P(X\le x) = \lim_{x\uparrow\infty} F(x) $ $\qquad\qquad$_...step (III)_

**My concerns are:**
**i.** Is this proof valid?
**ii.** Is the deduction of step (II) from (I) valid/math-rigor (especially the limit part)?
**iii** Is $y\uparrow\infty$ is same as $y\to\infty$ for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$?

**References**
(A)If events $A_n$ are non-decreasing in the sense $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$, then
$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \lim_{_m\to\infty} P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^m A_n\right)=\lim_{_m\to\infty}P(A_m)$

Comment: On the book proof, it might have been useful to add that for any real $x$, there is an integer $n_x$ such that $n_x\le x\lt n_x+1$, and that $F(n_x)\le F(x)\le F(n_x+1)$.  Let $x\to\infty$. Then $F(n_x)$ and $F(n_x+1)\to 1$, so by squeezing $F(x)\to 1$.

Comment: @ André Nicolas - Great stuff. Can't explain how much I appreciate it as I'm self studying these topics. Hope you could shed some light on the 2nd part of my post about the validity of my proof.

Comment: I do not see the point of the double-limit, which complicates matters, Take a sequence $(x_n)$ going to $\infty$, let $A_n$ be the event $X\le x_n$. Then the union of the $A_n$ has probability $1$.  Work exactly as in the book proof, but without the restriction $x_n=n$.

Comment: @ André Nicolas - Thanks a lot. Btw, is $y\uparrow\infty$ is same as $y\to\infty$ for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$? (I believe yes)

Comment: Effectively yes. Usually uparrow $a$ means approaches $a$ from below, but in the case "$a=\infty$" there is no alternative to from below.

Comment: @ André Nicolas - Thanks a lot.